# Vuelidate with I18n create a message for 'wrong password'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuelidate

I´m making these imports in my code

```
import { required, minLength, email  } from '@vuelidate/validators'
```

and I'm creating rules `withI18nmessage`

like this one

```
export const isEmail = withI18nMessage(email)
```

and I want to create a rule to check if the password is correct in login but im not finding the validator

Comment: How exactly are planning to check if a password is correct on the client side? It sounds like a bad idea…

Comment: yeah that´s true. I can see your point. I am having an error message when password validation throws an error that I need to translate. so I was trying to create a rule

Comment: Okay, for just translating you can use the `t()` function of i18n. Do you have imported i18n in your component or globally?

Comment: in my component. and I have some global keys. I was using that rules like "isEmail" to link the error with the keys in the component. but idk how to do it with the "wrong password" error

Comment: Can you add the full component code to your question?